# Web Based Linux Server Monitoring

Tags: linux, web-server, monitoring, web

I'm in search of a tool that would monitor my server, something like a phpSysInfo or munin.

I want to gather as much as possible so log parsing would be ideal. Also I need an opensource solution ideally based on Python. It could be just python lib - I would do the transferring to web on my own.

My initial idea is to create a statistics page that could be reaches with a browser.

I want to track:

- Uptime
- Data amount send/received true eth0, wlan0, etc
- Server load (cpu, ram, top processes)
- error logs entries (anything that goes in /var/log/)
- demons running
- login stats
- mysql state
- anything else

Comment: Please add more details like what all information you want to gather from the server.

Comment: @SparX, here you go. Updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Nagios is the best way to  Monitor all stuff on a server/s :)

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

With nagios you can monitor your server/s with plugins ..

you  use ssh  smtp or web based solutions
and if no plugin is aviable write your own one

Nagios gives you a very great web based monitoring tool:

With Nagios you can:

- Monitor your entire IT infrastructure
- Spot problems before they occur
- Know immediately when problems arise
- Share availability data with stakeholders
- Detect security breaches
- Plan and budget for IT upgrades
- Reduce downtime and business losses

And many many more..
At the moment are more than 2000 plugins aviable 
Like
Check_disk - check_proc (process) check_smtp ...

[plugins aviable](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins)

I like it its open source greez bull

Comment: I will definitively check that out! Yet it seems to be bit painful to extend such massive thing

Comment: Take a look at Icinga in combination with nConf. It's not that hard to set up and you can do all the configuration remotely in a nice web-editor.

Comment: Nagios is scalable for one server to 1000 server. The documentation is great and there are many configuration tools --> Tizon    nConf  or Lilac , NagiosQl OneCMDB Ignoramus .. and many config scrips but for a simple configuration read the documentation .. it is easier than it looks

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).
You can extend it on your own to use custom script in any language to gain data from your system, or use templates made by other users.

Comment: Front end is PHP, I really dislike PHP... But it showed my RRDTool, that is really nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zabbix](http://zabbix.com). It's very flexible and IMHO have rather small learning curve. No additional scripts are required - it has built-in [log file monitoring feature](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/log_file_monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

You have [PyMon](http://pymon.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't seem very alive anymore.

Comment: Requirements: `Python 2.4`, `Twisted 2.1+`, last commit was in 2009 - yup its dead.